# Ionicframework and new tag

Tags: ionic-framework, frameworks

How does ionicframework create new html tags like < ion-pane >? I didn't find any call to registerElement() in 'ionic.bundle.js' file.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic uses [AngularJS directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Search for `.directive('ionPane'` in your `ionic.bundle.js`.

Note that the directive names are case-sensitive camelCase normalized!

Comment: Thank you. I don't know AngulaJS, but maybe AngularJS compiles the html in tags body associating new functions. AngularJS doesn't register the new tags in DOM, if i don't wrong.

Comment: @giovanni_ Check https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler to see how AngularJS' "HTML compiler" works.

Comment: Thank you. I read: 'It's important to note that Angular operates on DOM nodes rather than strings.'
This means that Angolar parses 'document.body.childNodes' and then gets nodeName to search new tags, i think.